# how to achieve Dynamic URL in REST WebService

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop new web service for my application.
For that I am using `Spring REST-webservice`.
In the controller end, I am trying to fetch the list of records based on the agent passed.Now the requirement , the agent can be passed or it can be null.In case of null agent all records should be selected.else only those records to be fetched.

Tried using below code for achieving dynamism., as per one of the search result  however it is not working.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/staging/{agentCode: [^/]*?}" , method = 
RequestMethod.GET)
```

Here is my existing code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/batches")   
public class BatchController {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    @RequestMapping(value="/staging/{agentCode}", method = 
 RequestMethod.GET)         
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity IntmBatch(@PathVariable("agentCode") String 
   agentCode)       
   {
    //code here 
   }
```

**CASE 1**:when I use URL like .,

```
        www.example.com/myapplication/batches/staging/1234
```

it works fine and desired result is fetched.

**CASE 2**:However in case I am not passing any parameter say.,

```
    www.example.com/myapplication/batches/staging/
```

where in , I am not passing any parameter., it says me mapping not found.

Can you please let me know how to achieve this dynamic URL in `REST` GET Request Method Call.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/staging/{agentCode}", method = 
 RequestMethod.GET)         this means you are expecting agentCode in Request as mandatory . by this way you cannot achieve your expectation

Comment: I think you can have "/staging" and"/staging/{agentCode}" as two different services

Comment: This is ridiculous. You have two controller methods: `@RequestMapping(value = "/staging"` and `@RequestMapping(value = "/staging/{id}"`. That is how it is done in every application you will ever see. Instead you want  1 method but will have to implement the logic to decide what is required within that method. What exactly is the point?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `@Pathvariable` you can use `@RequestParam` for optional values in URL.

So your URL will be like.

**CASE 1** : `www.example.com/myapplication/batches/staging?agentCode=1234`  & 
**CASE 2** :  `www.example.com/myapplication/batches/staging`

Hope it will work solve your issue.

```
 @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
 @RequestMapping(value="/staging", method = RequestMethod.GET)         
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity IntmBatch(@RequestParam(name="agentCode",required=false) String   agentCode)       
   {
    //code here 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

create one more method in controller with @RequestMapping(value = "/staging", method = RequestMethod.GET) as follows.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/staging", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity returnAll() {
    System.out.println("returning  all ");
    // code here
return null;

}
```

Comment: yes.I can do this like the way mentioned above.However I would like to know if anything like regex  or such. Can solve my solution.This this will avoid one more method just for calling sake.